# I want to place another tile at the bottom of the tile with the highest number in the gridview

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final count = 10;
    final crossAxisCount = 3;
    final extra = (3 - (count % 3)) % 3;

    bool isEvenRow;

    return SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
        childAspectRatio: 2 / 2.4,
        children: List.generate(count + extra, (index) {
          isEvenRow = (index ~/ 3) % 2 == 0;
          int newIndex =
              isEvenRow ? index : (index ~/ 3 + 1) * 3 - 1 - index % 3;

            if (newIndex >= count) {
              return Column(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(

                    )),

              ]);
            }


          return Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    child: _gridTile(newIndex))),

          ]);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want the tile to be exposed in the "here" area, but I tried a lot, but it wasn't implemented correctly.
Another tile should be exposed at the bottom of the tile with the highest number, but it is difficult to implement because it has a unique grid view structure.